# Selenium 2 OnException method in c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, onexception

Am porting by Java codes to c#. I wanted to re-write the following Java code in c#. Thanks in advance :)

```
// Called whenever an exception would be thrown.
    public void onException(java.lang.Throwable throwable, WebDriver driver){
        System.out.println("onException' Called whenever an exception would be thrown ...");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A like to like translation is as follow:

```cs
public void OnException(System.Exception exception, IWebDriver driver)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnException' Called whenever an exception would be thrown ...");
}
```

Comment: This is a spectacularly incorrect statement. There most certainly is an implementation of EventFiringWebDriver. It's located in the WebDriver.Support.dll assembly.